# Encrypt with CryptoJS in JavaScript gives me different results from Java encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to replicate with CryptoJS an encryption done in Java using another library. The encryption's result in Java is `[111,60,-98,107,-60,5,-17,91,-52,60,-105,64,-88,31,97,-102,118,-39,-28,3,70,-12,21,-69,70,-22,-12,-91,102,-21,-88,5,82,-66,-122,34,14,-115,7,82,-55,38,-90,74,-4,62,104,104,61,-78,57,59,-51,31,84,-115,-45,-98,-87,-11,53,98,45,2,-52]` and I know that this is the correct payload. 
So, I am replicating the same encryption with the same values but I don't get the same array of bytes. The steps are:

- I transform the string message in a byteArray using utf-8
- If the byteArray is not divisible by 16, I add zeros until I arrive to a multiple of 16 (this is the request)
- I encrypt the bytearray using AES\ECB\NoPadding
- I transform the result of 'encrypted' in a byteArray

Here my code:

```
encryption() {
    let message = '{"cks":223,"com":31,token":1585040712404}'
    let shared1 = "24c27d724b86353c23390799bfc917f2679c96902f8280bd9926ce4a1ee0c23b"
    const shared = CryptoJS.SHA256(shared1);
    let byteMessage = new Buffer(message, 'utf8')
    if (byteMessage.length % 16 !== 0) {
        let emptyByte = new Buffer((Math.trunc(byteMessage.length / 16) + 1) * 16);
        for (let j = 0; j < byteMessage.length; j++) {
            emptyByte[j] = byteMessage[j] ? byteMessage[j] : 0
        }
        byteMessage = emptyByte;
    }
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(byteMessage.toString(), shared,
        {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
        });
    return this.wordArrayToByteArray(encrypted, 1);
}

wordArrayToByteArray(wordArray, length): Promise<any> {
    if (wordArray.hasOwnProperty("ciphertext") && wordArray.ciphertext.hasOwnProperty('sigBytes') && wordArray.ciphertext.hasOwnProperty('words')) {
        length = wordArray.ciphertext.sigBytes;
        wordArray = wordArray.ciphertext.words;
    }

    var result = [],
        bytes,
        i = 0;
    while (length > 0) {
        bytes = this.wordToByteArray(wordArray[i], Math.min(4, length));
        length -= bytes.length;
        result.push(bytes);
        i++;
    }
    return [].concat.apply([], result);
}


wordToByteArray(word, length) {
    var ba = [],
        i,
        xFF = 0xFF;
    if (length > 0)
        ba.push(word >>> 24);
    if (length > 1)
        ba.push((word >>> 16) & xFF);
    if (length > 2)
        ba.push((word >>> 8) & xFF);
    if (length > 3)
        ba.push(word & xFF);

    return ba;
}
```

The result of this function is `[252, 55, 222, 129, 178, 237, 141, 108, 104, 113, 232, 152, 168, 114, 250, 185, 198, 211, 105, 25, 4, 141, 152, 14, 177, 251, 109, 160, 70, 119, 253, 204, 126, 211, 250, 96, 114, 151, 196, 180, 238, 94, 11, 68, 44, 166, 158, 47]` that is completely different from the correct one.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The data seem to be inconsistent: If the posted plaintext is UTF8 encoded, the result is 41 bytes, so padding with `0x00`-values would result in 48 bytes, which would also be the length of the AES-ECB-ciphertext. But the _posted_ ciphertext is 65 bytes long. Furthermore, its length doesn't correspond to an integer multiple of 16 as it should be for AES-ECB. So check the data. Also post the Java code for encryption.

Comment: I do not have the Java code...but, supposing you are right, why, with my code, is 64 bytes long? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding your last edit: How do you know that the key is the SHA256 hash of `shared1`? `shared1` could also be hexadecimal encoded.

Comment: I know it by documentation of my project

Comment: Sure? With a hexadecimal encoding I can at least reconstruct the 1st block of your posted ciphertext. Can you provide reliable test data?  As I said before, the posted ciphertext doesn't correspond to the plaintext and mode regarding the length.

Comment: I edited my code with my improvements...I now get a byteArray of lenght 48. Is it correct? I mean, the length should be correct, according to what you said, but is it the correct way?

Comment: _but is it the correct way?_ I can't answer that without knowing the Java code (because it's the reference) or without consistent test data! Before, you returned a buffer with the Base64 encoded ciphertext, now a Java array with the ciphertext. One is as right as the other. One more note: CryptoJS supports Zero-padding.